# Is fs.readFile() an asynchronous function?

Tags: node.js

I'm assuming **NO** because it returns a `void` instead of `Promise<void>`, however, the documentation states the following sentence:

*Asynchronously reads the entire contents of a file.*

How does this function read a file asynchronously if it's not an async function?

Comment: Lots of things in nodejs are asynchronous, but are not `async` functions.  Look at `setTimeout()` for example.  `async` is just one tool you can use to manage and communicate asynchronous completion.  It is not the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is asynchronous.

It does not return anything (let alone a promise (and a promise that resolved as void (nothing) would be pointless).

It accepts a callback that will be called when the result is available.

See [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) which says, explicitly:

> Asynchronously reads the entire contents of a file.

and has an example of how to use it:

> ```
> import { readFile } from 'fs';
>
> readFile('/etc/passwd', (err, data) => {
>   if (err) throw err;
>   console.log(data);
> });
> ```

[A version that returns a promise](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options) is also available.

Comment: Ok bear with me a bit, I thought that async functions were supposed to return a promise. When I use the async keyword The function automatically returns a promise. How do you create an async function that doesn't return a promise?

Comment: That's how the `async` keyword works, not how asynchronous functions work in general. `fs.readFile` predates the existence of `async` and `await` (and Promises for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is an asynchronous function because it takes a callback and calls callback function when the data is ready.
That's why it is asynchronous.

Example from the doc:

```js
readFile('/etc/passwd', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readfile` is asynchronous and can return a result later by calling a callback that you should indicate for it:

```
fs.readFile(path[, options], callback)
```

So if you are not interested in the result of `readFile` call immediately (at the next line) after this call you can use it. Otherwise use `readFile` from `fs/promises` package that returns Promise